# MVC DotNetOpenAuth with colorbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, colorbox, dotnetopenauth

I'm trying to open a modal window (jQuery colorbox) when the users doing login with facebook or twitter with DotNetOpenAuth. I doing an post with jQuery, but I haven't any idea why I haven't a response.

This is the HTML

```
<form returnurl="" action="/account/externalLogin" id="ExternalLogin" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
     <fieldset id="socialLoginList">
          <legend>Log in using another service</legend>
               <p>
                    <button type="submit" name="provider" class="lightbox" value="twitter" title="Log in using your Twitter account">Twitter</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="provider" class="lightbox" value="facebook" title="Log in using your Facebook account">Facebook</button>
               </p>
     </fieldset>
</form>
```

And this my javascript

```
$("#ExternalLogin").submit(function () {
     $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
          alert(data);
     }, 'html');

     return false;
});
```

Never I have a response from $.post. What I'm doing bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [How can i supply an AntiForgeryToken when posting JSON data using $.ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906754/how-can-i-supply-an-antiforgerytoken-when-posting-json-data-using-ajax?rq=1)

If you're using the standard account controller that comes in MVC 4 projects you'll be hitting ExternalLogin which has the attribute [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] - you can confirm this by reading your error message.

You need to send back this token otherwise the server will give you a 500 internal error.