# ASP.net Identity send AntiForgeryToken from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-identity

With ASP.net MVC 5 comes Account Controller and Account Views. In Register view there is line

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

And above register controller there is attribute:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
```

I've decided to send data to server from javascript using JSON (I'm using Angular and $http.post method).

My question is how can I send this AntiForgeryToken using javascript and Validate it in controller ?

And are there any more security measures I should include ?

Comment: I *think* you'd just need to look for the input with the name "__RequestVerificationToken" and submit that with your post data (using the same name). The controller should handle all of the verification logic.

Comment: Please can you tell me how to do that ? (look for the input)

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[0].value`

Comment: Hm some searching led me to [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17988051/1810243) which is what I was thinking about. That links [to this old SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906754/how-can-i-supply-an-antiforgerytoken-when-posting-json-data-using-ajax).

Comment: Thank you very much, I've done it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AngularJS has built-in support for XSRF (AKA anti forgery)

> XSRF is a technique by which an unauthorized site can gain your user's
>   private data. Angular provides a mechanism to counter XSRF. When
>   performing XHR requests, the $http service reads a token from a cookie
>   (by default, XSRF-TOKEN) and sets it as an HTTP header (X-XSRF-TOKEN).
>   Since only JavaScript that runs on your domain could read the cookie,
>   your server can be assured that the XHR came from JavaScript running
>   on your domain. The header will not be set for cross-domain requests.

If you want to take advantage of this functionality, you have to create action filters that will create and verify the XSRF-TOKEN cookie.
Here is a simplified version of what I use.

AntiForgeryTokenCookieAttribute - use this attribute to add the XSRF-TOKEN cookie

```
/// <summary>
/// Create a XSRF token in the XSRF-TOKEN cookie which is automatically read by AngularJS
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class AntiForgeryTokenCookieAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IAntiForgeryVerificationTokenStore _verificationTokenStore = new AntiForgeryVerificationTokenCookieStore(); //TODO: make configurable
    private const string CookieName = "XSRF-TOKEN"; //TODO: make configurable

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var oldVerificationToken = _verificationTokenStore.GetVerificationToken(filterContext.HttpContext.Request);

        string newVerificationToken;
        string newToken;
        AntiForgery.GetTokens(oldVerificationToken, out newVerificationToken, out newToken);

        if (newVerificationToken != null)
        {
            _verificationTokenStore.StoreVerificationToken(filterContext.HttpContext.Response, newVerificationToken);
        }

        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(CookieName, newToken));
    }
}
```

ValidateAntiForgeryTokenHeaderAttribute

```
/// <summary>
/// Validate the XSRF token stored in the X-XSRF-TOKEN header.
/// If the header doesn't exist, look for the XSRF token in the from post.
/// 
/// Compatible with ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class ValidateAntiForgeryTokenHeaderAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly IAntiForgeryVerificationTokenStore _verificationTokenStore = new AntiForgeryVerificationTokenCookieStore(); //TODO: make configurable
    private const string TokenHeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN"; //TODO: make configurable

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var token = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers[TokenHeaderName];
        if (token != null)
        {
            //validate the token stored in header
            var verificationToken = _verificationTokenStore.GetVerificationToken(filterContext.HttpContext.Request);
            if (verificationToken == null) { throw new HttpAntiForgeryException("Required verification token not found"); }
            AntiForgery.Validate(verificationToken, token);
        }
        else
        {
            //validate the token stored in form. Same as ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute
            AntiForgery.Validate();
        }
    }
}
```

IAntiForgeryVerificationTokenStore

```
public interface IAntiForgeryVerificationTokenStore
{
    string GetVerificationToken(HttpRequestBase request);
    void StoreVerificationToken(HttpResponseBase response, string token);
}
```

AntiForgeryVerificationTokenCookieStore

```
public class AntiForgeryVerificationTokenCookieStore : IAntiForgeryVerificationTokenStore
{
    public string GetVerificationToken(HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        if (request == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("request"); }

        var token = request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];
        return token != null ? token.Value : null;
    }

    public void StoreVerificationToken(HttpResponseBase response, string token)
    {
        if (response == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("response"); }
        if (token == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("token"); }

        response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName, token) { HttpOnly = true, Secure = AntiForgeryConfig.RequireSsl });
    }
}
```