# ajax antiforgery token json

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, antiforgerytoken

I am securing my application against cross-site scripting using anti forgery token 
Development environment is VS 2012, MVC4, knockout

I have placed anti-forgery token as follows

```
<form id="__AjaxAntiForgeryForm" action="#" method="post"><%= Html.AntiForgeryToken()%></form>
```

In my ajax call I also want to send data. My ajax call is as follows

```
            $.ajax({
                url: VirtualDir + '/Tasks/StartTask/',
                asynch: false,
                type: 'POST',
                data: { "__RequestVerificationToken": token, oTaskData: JSON.stringify(item), whichTab: self.CurrentTab },
                success: function (data) {
                    InitializeData(data);
                    self.LoadData(data);
                }
            })
        };
```

My controller code is as follows

```
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize]
    public JsonResult StartTask(TaskData oTaskData, string whichTab)
    {
        int TaskID = oTaskData.TaskID;
        int LoggedInEmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["EmployeeID"]);
        TaskRepository oTaskRepository = new TaskRepository();
        return Json(oTaskRepository.TaskChangeStatus(TaskID, LoggedInEmployeeID, TaskConstants.IN_PROGRESS, whichTab), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In controller, value of whichTab parameter is received but oTaskData is null
If I remove anti-forgery token then data is received properly in controller

How can I use antiforgery token along with JSON data?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906754/how-can-i-supply-an-antiforgerytoken-when-posting-json-data-using-ajax

Comment: You are missing [HttpPost] Attribute on you method.

Comment: I have already checked that question. The difference is in that example only one parameter is passed which of type int. In my case I am sending object.

Comment: It is not working even after adding  [HttpPost]

Answer (score 0):

When sending multiple values in JSON. You have stringify like this:

I am separating JSON string from the Ajax Request to make it clear.

```
    var sData = JSON.stringify({
       __RequestVerificationToken : token,
       oTaskData: item,
       whichTab: self.CurrentTab
    });
```

In Ajax Request Add this: `contentType: 'application/json'`,
To show you are sending Json data.

and you are returning Json, so also `dataType: 'json'`

```
 $.ajax({
      url: VirtualDir + '/Tasks/StartTask/',
      asynch: false,
      type: 'POST',
      data: sData,
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: 'json'
                success: function (data) {
                    InitializeData(data);
                    self.LoadData(data);
                }
            });
```

**EDIT:**

If the Above doesn't work then use Answer here: 
Use the HEADER of Ajax request.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24394578/1910735

```
var headers = {};
headers['__RequestVerificationToken'] = token;

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/MyTestMethod',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    headers: headers,
    data: JSON.stringify({
         oTaskData: item,
           whichTab: self.CurrentTab
    }),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function () {},
    error: function (xhr) {}
});
```

You will have to create this Attribute Class : `ValidateJsonAntiForgeryTokenAttribute`, You can see in the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24394578/1910735

Comment: It is not even going to controller

Comment: Have you got [HttpPost] Attribute on your method in controller?