# Typeahead.js for mvc5 models

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, typeahead.js

I've just downloaded and installed

- typeahead.bundle.min.js
- typeahead.mvc.model.js
- typeahead.css

I've followed the example given and I have a helper in my view

`@Html.AutocompleteFor(model => model.NewUser.User_Org, model => model.NewUser.User_Org,"GetOrganisations", "User", false, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })`

and this action method on my controller

```
[ActionName("GetOrganisations")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult GetComboData(string search)
    {
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            GetOrganisationRequestNonPrimary request = new GetOrganisationRequestNonPrimary(search);
            result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
            var organisations = this._organisationService.OrganisationAutoComplete(request);
            result.Data = organisations.Organisations.AsQueryable();
            result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The input box is rendered but when I start typing, nothing happens, I would expect my action method to be hit on the controller, but it isn't.  I've got all the prerequisites for typeahead and the mvc helper, yet it just wont work.  Is there something I'm  missing?

Comment: Can you possibly show the rendered output of the helper?  Does that contain the JavaScript to initialize the plugin?

Comment: Why the duplicate line `result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;`?  Not your issue I think but just curious.

Comment: the problem seemed to be related to the antiforgerytoken.  Its included in the form but not pased to the controller action so i commented it out and the controller code is now being hit and its returning some data.  The problem now is its not being displayed, the drop down appears and its empty, but I still ant explain the antiforgerytoken problem

Comment: duplicate JsonRequestBehaviour was just an error, removing it made no difference

Comment: this is whats rendered, the only javascript are the libraries typeahead.bundle.min and typeahead.mvc.model

Comment: <div class="col-md-5">
                

                

                <label class="control-label" for="NewUser_End_User_Org">Organisation</label>
                <span class="twitter-typeahead" style="position: relative; display: inline-block;"><input class="typeahead tt-hint" data-autocomplete-id-field="NewUser_End_User_Org" data-autocomplete-url="/User/GetOrganisations" type="text" value="" readonly="" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="-1" dir="ltr" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border-color: transparent; box-shadow: none; opacity: 1; background: n

Comment: sorry, the markup was over 1000 characters too long so ive had to truncate it, hopefully this will be of some help

Comment: Put that in the question and format it for visibility.  Include any script it has included/generates as well.

Comment: Look here for clues on the token issue, I wondered about that but did not dig into the JS code.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906754/how-can-i-supply-an-antiforgerytoken-when-posting-json-data-using-ajax