# DotNetCore Using AntiForgeryToken in Header

Tags: json, asp.net-core, http-headers

I am trying to send my HTTP requests as `content-type:application/json`. So, because my data sended as JSON, I also send AntiForgeryToken as JSON:

```json
{
    "SearchValue": "ShiroiTora",
    "Filter": [
        {
            "FilterName": "DepartmentIdList",
            "FilterValue": [
                "1",
                "2",
                "3"
            ]
        }   
    ],
    "TotalCount": "1000",
    "PageNumber": "1",
    "OrderColumn": "Name"
},
//{
//  "__RequestVerificationToken": "*some_token_here"
//}
```

I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48705369/net-core-forgery-token-validation-in-json?noredirect=1#comment84409323_48705369) what should I do my code to understand JSON-ised AntiForgeryToken. I don't know whether it's possible or not, but [as described in this site](https://nozzlegear.com/blog/send-and-validate-an-asp-net-antiforgerytoken-as-a-request-header) it looks like it's possible to send AntiForgeryToken value in header. But the code is written in .net mvc and I couldn't find any code written in ".net core 2.0". Also, I don't know much about "Attributes" so, it would be appreciated if someone could help me.

My Code (I am not sure if I should copy/paste code written in "that site" or not. So, I just copy/paste my code):

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult PhoneBook([FromBody]PersonnelFilterReq filterList)
{
    return Ok("FINALLY WORKED!!!!");
}
```

Model (used in POST method):

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GebzeShared.Modules.HR.Personnel.RequestModels
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Personel sayfaları için genel request metodu
    /// </summary>
    public class PersonnelFilterReq
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Arama Değeri
        /// </summary>
        public string SearchValue { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Filtre Listesi
        /// </summary>
        public ICollection<FilterList> Filter { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public int TotalCount { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public int PageNumber { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public string OrderColumn { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public class FilterList
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Filterinin Adı
        /// </summary>
        public string FilterName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Filtrenin Değeri
        /// </summary>
        public ICollection<string> FilterValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ASP.NET MVC Core it is not necessary anymore to use a custom attribute as done on the site you refer to. It works out of the box now to set the token in the header of an ajax request. [See example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery#javascript)