# Combine 2 JSON objects in JQUERY

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

Could you please help me on how to combine the below Result1 and Result2 JSON objects into single JSON such that i have Name,No,Avg,Subject1,Subject2 into single JSON object. I am using it in JQUERY AJAX.

```
{"Result1":"[{"NAME" : "Mark","No" : "23544","Avg" : "49"}]"}

{"Result2":"[{"Subject1" : "Maths","Subject2" : "Computers"}]"}
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Check the following links.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617036/appending-to-a-json-object

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433627/concat-json-objects

Comment: Your examples are not valid JSON.

Answer (score 5):

See [`jQuery.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend)

```
var x = {"Result1":"[{"NAME" : "Mark","No" : "23544","Avg" : "49"}]"}
var y = {"Result2":"[{"Subject1" : "Maths","Subject2" : "Computers"}]"}

var z = jQuery.extend({}, x.Result1[0], y.Result2[0]);
// z.NAME, z.No, z.Avg, z.subject1...
```

I'm not sure whether you've parsed the JSON string into a JavaScript object yet; but see [`jQuery.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON) to see how you do this (be aware; `parseJSON()` will throw an error if you pass it invalid JSON).

Comment: +1 This will work, assuming the OP makes his code into valid JSON objects