# combining two json objects?

Tags: jquery, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combine 2 JSON objects in JQUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310204/combine-2-json-objects-in-jquery)

I'm creating a facebook app with node on the backend to get the album list and show the cover photo for each. It needs to be done with two calls, one to get a list of albums, another to get the cover photo with the id of a particular album

my code looks something like this

```
 $('#main').on('click', '#albums', function() {
      $.get('/albums', function(data) {
           for (i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
                $.get('/cover-photo?id=' + data.data[i].cover_photo, function(dataz) {
                     data+=dataz;
                });
            }
            console.log(data);
       });
  });
```

the reason I want it all in one object is because I'm using javascript templating and it'd be better to just have one object that has everything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to combine this object for using tepmplate enging I will suggest you just add a another key with the same object so you can access all information of album and also with that each album cover photo object.

Like:

```
$('#main').on('click', '#albums', function() {
 $.get('/albums', function(data) {
   for(i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
    $.get('/cover-photo?id=' + data.data[i].cover_photo, function(dataz) {
      data.data[i].coverPhotoObj = dataz;
      //this new key with perticular album object will hold that cover photo object details
    });
  }
 console.log(data);
});});
```

Comment: eg.

Object {data: Array[25], paging: Object}
 good:22
25
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'coverPhotoObj' of undefined

Comment: you can set just before get request data.data[i].coverPhotoObj = {}; otherwise till you ajax is not done it say undefined

Comment: like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/h8gRU/1/

same error

Comment: I just made some update in this code check this http://jsfiddle.net/wag6d/

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$.extend({},firstobject,secoundobject)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [jquery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) :

```
jQuery.extend({}, json1, json2);
```