# append json objects into json array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and would like to append the contents of it to an existing array. 
I am using `JSON.stringify( $('#myForm').serializeObject() )` to convert my form elements into `json` objects. 
The form has user info that i would like to append into `myArr` then append this list into an existing array. 
`myArr` is populating fine, its just appending that into `existingJsonArray` i seem to be having problems with.
I [saw this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617036/appending-to-a-json-object) but since `JSON.stringify` creates the full json array would i need to knock out the `[{` and `}]` ?
Is this the correct approach?

```
var existingJsonArray = [];
var myArr = [];

myArr.unshift( JSON.stringify( $('#myForm').serializeObject() ) );

existingJsonArray.unshift(myArr);
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify` does not create an object, but a string from an object.

Comment: Maybe you should be using JSON.parse, as you seem to have them confused ?

Comment: @adeneo where would i use `JSON.parse`?

Comment: `$('#myForm').serializeObject() ` already returns object.

Comment: JSON is a *string* format.  It is a *string representation* of a data structure.  There is no such thing as a "JSON object" or a "JSON array".

Comment: @tq - who knows, you're just saying three times that you are creating an object with JSON.stringify, which of course stringifies an object to JSON format, and JSON.parse would be the opposite, and actual create an object from a string, but you're mixin jQuery methods that already does this for you, so it's a bit uneccessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please notice that [JSON](http://json.org/) is the *string representation* of objects - and not suited well for manipulating them.

```
var array = [], // an Array literal in JavaScript code
    formObject;
formObject = $('#myForm').serializeObject(); // an object representing the form
array.unshift([formObject]); // not sure why you need the nested array
// create string containing JSON representation of the array:
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(array);
```