# How to store JSON in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to store data as JSON like a database,
so that when a user registers the information should be stored in a variable?

Example:

My HTML form consists of input text fields firstname, lastname. Clicking the register button of the form should store the values of firstname and lastname in a variables.

How can I do this:

```
 var txt = '{"employees":[' +
   '{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
    '{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
     '{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';
```

Comment: you can use `var json = JSON.parse(txt)`

Comment: @ArunPJohny I think OP is asking for the other direction

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use JSON? You cannot really process it further since it is just text. A simple object or array would be more appropriate.

Comment: i did not have much knowledge on JSON can you please tell me a good source for it @ArunPJohny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easily use Jquery

```
var jsonArray;
jsonArray.push($("#firstname").val();
jsonArray.push($("#lastname").val();
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonArray);
```

Comment: The only part that is jQuery is `$("...").val()`. Otherwise your code is full of syntax errors, runtime errors and uses confusing variable names (like `jsonArray`). If you would initialize `jsonArray` properly, then it would contain a normal JS array, not JSON.

Comment: Looking at this solution again, almost two years later, I have to agree with Felix: it will not work. The first line needs to be at least `var jsonArray=[];` to be consistent with the rest. But even then all the names found (firstname and lastname alike) will be thrown together into this simple array. The input fields might not even be found if their `id` attributes don't hold the same values as their `name` attributes. OP only mentioned the `name` attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to go from values in *HTML* to a *JSON* string. Assuming `<form>` looks like this

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" name="nm1[]"/><input type="text" name="nm2[]"/>
    <input type="text" name="nm1[]"/><input type="text" name="nm2[]"/>
</form>
```

You can use [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName) twice, build an *Object* and [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) it

```js
var nm1 = document.getElementsByName('nm1[]'),
    nm2 = document.getElementsByName('nm2[]'),
    i, o = {
        employees: []
    };
for (i = 0; i < nm1.length; ++i) {
    if (nm1[i].value && nm2[i].value)
        o.employees.push({
            firstName: nm1[i].value,
            lastName: nm2[i].value
        });
}
JSON.stringify(o);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eqjXs/) (open console)

Answer (score 1):

You can add data to the actual data structure by appending it to the `employees` array like

```
dataobj.employees.push({"firstName":$('input[name=firstn]').val(),
                        "lastName":$('input[name=lastn]').val() });
```

Of course, this requires that the JSON was parsed into the dataobj in the first place. It must be serialized again if you want to send it by `GET`. But it can be `POST`ed directly as a data object!

You can of course also start with an empty array, initializing dataobj like

```
var dataobj={ employee: [] };
```

before the above uptdating command comes into action.

**A *very late* edit ...**

Just in case there should be multiple firstname / lastname input fields, then the following will do a "much better" job (as it will have a look at all fields and collect only those where at least one of the names is set):

```js
var dataobj={employees:[]};
function shw(){
  $('#out').text(JSON.stringify(dataobj).replace(/{/g,'\n{'));}
$(function(){
  $('#clr').click(function(){dataobj.employees=[];shw()});
  $('#go').click(function(){
   var ln=$('input[name=lastn]').toArray();     // ln: JS-Array of DOM elements
   $('input[name=firstn]').each(function(i,fn){ // for each fn DOM-element ...
    var f=fn.value,l=ln[i].value;               // get values as strings
    if (f+l>'') dataobj.employees.push({firstName:f,lastName:l}); // push name object
   });shw();})
  shw();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="firstn" value="John"><input type="text" name="lastn" value="Doe"><br>
<input type="text" name="firstn" value="Anna"><input type="text" name="lastn" value="Smith"><br>
<input type="text" name="firstn" value="Peter"><input type="text" name="lastn" value="Jones">
<input type="button" id="go" value="append names">
<input type="button" id="clr" value="clear">
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `push` method of array to push JSON data. This is shown here - [appending-to-a-json-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617036/appending-to-a-json-object). Before the data needs to be submitted (say to `process.php`), [stringify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593046/jquery-json-to-string) it.

Comment: The OP doesn't have an array, they have text.