# How to pass array to the object in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Suppose my JSON is:

```
{
  "todo" : "Dinner",
  "user" : [
    {
      "name" : "",
      "password" : ""
    }
  ],
  "notes : "some notes"
}
```

And I want to formulate the object from that JSON.

So in angularjs, first I can do the following to formulate the user array:

```
userArray = [{
                name: 'myname',
                password: 'password'
            }];
```

And my object without userArray is as follows:

```
var object = {};
object.todo = "Dinner";
object.notes = "some notes";
```

Now how to add `userArray` to this `object` to get the complete object?

Comment: Surely just `object.user = userArray`?

Comment: wow, it was so simple. Thanks.

Comment: How to add the userArray dynamically in a loop? See my update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appending to an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617036/appending-to-an-object)

Answer (score 0):

Just set the array to your scope object in the controller. Angular has nothing to do with this. Its plain JavaScript.

```
$scope.object.user = userArray;
```

Comment: How to add the userArray dynamically in a loop? See my update.

Comment: @MyGod - probably best to ask a new question at this late stage, particularly since the question has now changed!

Comment: sure this is done here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700686/adding-object-to-an-array-dynamically