# Adding object to an array dynamically

Tags: angularjs

In angularjs, I can do the following to formulate the user array:

```
userArray = [{
                name: 'myname',
                password: 'password'
            }];
```

How to add the userArray in a loop dynamically so that by adding another one, the json will be:

```
userArray = [{
                name: 'myname',
                password: 'password'
            },
            {
                name: 'othername',
                password: 'otherpassword'
            }
            ];
```

I used angular.forEach for a loop:

```
var someObject = {};
var userArray = [];
var i = 0;
angular.forEach(selectedOnes, function(user) {
     userArray = [{
                     name: user.name,
                     password: user.password
                  }];

                if(i == 0)
                {
                    someObject.someArray= userArray;    
                }
                else
                {
                    someObject.someArray+= userArray;       
                }
                i++;
             }
```

The above code is returning `[object Object][object Object]` for `i=2`. Similarly, it returns `[object Object][object Object][object Object]` for `i=3` and so on..so is not adding correctly.

Comment: Ever heard of `push`? `userArray.push({name: 'othername',password: 'otherpassword'})` I mean it's basics of JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `push`.

`userArray.push({name: 'Your name',password: 'The password'})`

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks. I tried using push but in a wrong way. Your solution worked.